# show brands on home.html stencil theme bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using BigCommerce Theme for my website and I was trying to show Brands on homepage. I used below mentioned code but it does not give any output. Here is my code

```
<ul class="brandGrid">
    {{#each brands}}
        <li class="brand">
            <article class="card {{#if alternate}}card--alternate{{/if}}">
                <figure class="card-figure">
                    <a href="{{url}}">
                        <img class="card-image" src="{{getImage image 'brand_size' (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_brand)}}" alt="{{name}}" title="{{name}}">
                    </a>
                </figure>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </article>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: on the home page where would you like to show and which format like the slider or simple text?

Comment: Show it below banner. format - slider